# angularjs update view after $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `<ul>` in my html view and the content of this `<ul>` is populated based on a $http.get.

HTML:

```
    <div id="recentlyReleased" ng-controller="sampleRecordController as recCtrl">
    <h1>Sample Records</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="last-child" ng-repeat="record in recCtrl.records">
            <a target="_new" ng-href="" >
                <span>sample 1</span>

            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
     <a ng-click="recCtrl.displayRecords('a')" href="">
         <img />
     </a>
     <a ng-click="recCtrl.displayRecords('b')" href="">
         <img />
     </a>
</div>
```

**factory**

```
angular.module('homeApp.services', [])
    .factory('homePage', function ($http) {
        return {
            showRecords: function (fac) {
                return $http.get('/home/getRandom?num=10&fac=' + fac)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return response.data
                        });
            }               
        }

    }

    );
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('homeApp.controllers')
    .controller('sampleRecordController', function (homePage) {
        var r = this;
        r.base_url = base_url;
        r.records = [];
        var currentFac='c';
        r.displayRecords = function (fac) {
            homePage.setFac(fac);
            homePage.showRecords(homePage.getFac()).then(function (data) {
                r.records = data;
            });

        },
        r.displayRecords(currentFac); //initial load

    })
```

The code initially load the list`<ul>` successfully, but when I clicked on the `<a>`, the html view does not get refreshed. I'm a newbie in angularjs could someone please help? Thanks

Comment: it should work..could you reproduce the problem in plunkr/jsfiddle?

Comment: I see two separate questions here: 1) loading the `ul`, 2) clicking the `a`. Please try to ask questions that follow these guidelines: http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be trying to do is return the promise of $http.get() like below.

```
angular.module('homeApp.services', [])
.factory('homePage', function ($http) {
    return {
        showRecords: function (fac) {
            // return the promise here
            return $http.get('/home/getRandom?num=10&fac=' + fac);
        }               
    }

});

angular.module('homeApp.controllers')
.controller('sampleRecordController', function (homePage) {
    var r = this;
    r.base_url = base_url;
    r.records = [];
    var currentFac='c';
    r.displayRecords = function (fac) {
        homePage.setFac(fac);
        homePage.showRecords() // resolve here
        .then(function (data) {
            r.records = data;
        });

    },
    r.displayRecords(currentFac); //initial load

});
```

NOTE: You cannot return the response of a ajax call because it runs on a different thread and you'll not know when the call is going to complete. You should try learning about promises.

Comment: Thanks, If i run debug r.records is changing but the html view is not refreshing. I will look at promises...

Comment: Can you post the response of the $http.get() request?

Comment: The code is not wrong, returning response.data creates a new promise that resolves with that instead of response.